# android - how to download and change icon of GCM notification dynamically

Tags: android, notifications, icons, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app that receives notification. What I want to do is I'll pass an icon url to the app through GCM. when app received message and `onMessage` is called, the app should download the icon from url and display it in notification. the problem I'm having now is how to set the icon dynamically? how do I know the int value of the icon I just download? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Notification API doesn't seem to support setting a small icon with a bitmap, it does support setting large icon with a bitmap though, so you can use the method `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToIcon, options)` to decode your downloaded icon and set it to the large icon.

For small icons (which appears on the status bar on the phone briefly when notification arrives), you may need to store a list of your custom icons in the phone, and have the content of the GCM message to tell your app which icon to show. e.g. you could have "icon_1.png", "icon_2.png", "icon_3.png" in your drawables, then your GCM message could have an "icon_number" attribute, which tells the app which icon should be shown.